# Convenience method to create array of percentages from another array

Tags: php

I would like to perform the following server-side in PHP...

If I have one array like this: `$array1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`, can I create another array which contains the percent of each value (each value divided by the total)? Is there a way to do this without brute forcing with a for loop? I essentially want to create array2

`sum_array($array1)` produces 55 (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55)

`$array2 = array(1.8%, 3.6%, 5.4%, 7.2%, 9%, 10.9%, 12.7%, 15.5%, 16.3%, 18.2%)`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this.

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$total = array_sum($array1);

$array2 = array_map(function($a) use($total){
    return round(($a*100) / $total, 1) . '%';
}, $array1);
```

Comment: Beat me by 15 seconds... I'll just +1 yours instead. Also +1 for `use()` - I hadn't thought of that and was wondering how the callback could reference `$total` without resorting to a global.

Comment: Since it can't be done without looping (and `array_map` does the looping here) +1 for a good answer!

Comment: @Utkanos: Yeah, `use` is weird.  I learned about it, and I love trying to use it (pun intended) in various situations.

Comment: @Utkanos for the use of `use` I would give him +2 if I could :)

Comment: @Rocket I knew that someone smarter than me would come up with a great solution. Thanks

Comment: @Derek: You're welcome. :-)  You may want to play with the rounding to get it the way you want it.